# Binded DataGridView problem

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a binded DataGridView that allows adding new rows. The problem is that a new object is automatically inserted in the binding source when the CurrentRow is the last grid row.
I want that a new object to be added to the binding source only when the user starts typing in one of the last row cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way `DataGridView` works, and having tried before to change the way adding new items works, I have to caution you against trying it.

Your best option is to have your binding source implement the `ICancelAddNew` interface. If this interface is implemented, then the `DataGridView` will call `CancelNew` if the user leaves the row without entering any data into the new item. You can also use a `BindingList<T>` as your data source, or wrap your data source in a `BindingSource`; both of these classes implement `ICancelAddNew`.